# margin top wtih js for many div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 30 box (for example) and I need to add custom margin top for each div **with JS**.

```
div : margin-top:0px;
div : margin-top:10px;
div : margin-top:20px;
div : margin-top:30px;
and ..
.
.
```

### .

**This is my js code.**

```
var n = $('div');
n.css('margin-top', (parseFloat(n.css('margin-top')) + 10) + 'px');
```

**Result:**

```
 div : margin-top:10px;
    div : margin-top:10px;
    div : margin-top:10px;
    div : margin-top:10px;
    and ..
    .
    .
    .
```

How can I do this?

Comment: if this is duplicate, please send me a link!

Comment: "How can I do this?" is not a valid question. It is much too broad for Stack Overflow, especially when you show no attempt or research of your own.

Comment: @santi please check again. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is a bit messy. `$("div")` is going to be a *collection* of `<div>` elements, so you'll need to do slightly more to actually move through and address them each individually.

Luckily, jQuery's [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) does just that. Multiplying the `index` by 10 should result in a `10px` increase in each:

```
$("div").each(function(index) {
    var margin = index * 10;
    $(this).css("margin-top", margin+"px");
});
```